# ERROR ITMS-9000 iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload a `phonegap` build `iOS` app to the app store and I keep getting this error

`ERROR-ITMS-9000:: "Missing Code Signing Entitlements. No entitlements found in the bundle 'com.fitness.challenges' for executable 'Payload/30DayFitness.app/30DayFitness'." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)`

I have set up my development and distribution provisioning profiles and certificates, and uploaded the `cerificate.12` and provision profile to `build.phonegap.com`

any help be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed this by adding -538h to the iphone5 splash screen png file name!

so it was - splash-iphone5-538h.png

that was all that was breaking the upload!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this topic on phonegap build support forum](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/error_itms_9000_missing_code_signing_entitlements?utm_content=reply_link&utm_medium=email&utm_source=reply_notification#reply_13126257) there's an error in documentation.

In config.xml as id you should put just your app name and not the reverse style domain id as used in provisioning profile.

**EDIT: (16.10.2013, 17:33)**

I just discovered that it is rather temporary workaround because to upload APK in play store you'd still need the reverse style domain id.

Answer (score 0):

check your Bundle Identifier. 
The bundle id supposed to same with App ID.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by making sure all the required icons where there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a RE-SIGNED APP, using [iResign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign]iResign) as the re-signing tool.

Here's an example of an Entitlements.plist file that helped me get my build through to Apple.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>application-identifier</key>
       <string>B123RP1C12.com.startup.killerapp</string>
       <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
       <array>
            <string>B123RP1C12.com.startup.killerapp </string>
       </array>
       <key>get-task-allow</key>
       <true/>
    </dict>
 </plist>
```