# What can I do to get past the multiple errors listed below that I'm receiving when trying to submit my iOS app to the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode5

[image: This is a screenshot of the errors i'm receiving]

I'm unable to figure out how to get past these errors after countless hours of research. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385684/error-itms-9000-itunes-connect

Comment: None of the solutions in that post fix my issue, I checked everything.

Comment: Well, I did say "possible".  Given the minimal information provided, one can only guess.  Please provide additional information.

Comment: This might be an obvious question, but... Did you specify entitlements for your project?

Comment: Where exactly would that be done? I have submitted an app before without issue but never knew about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by not including a plus symbol anywhere in my app name. I understand there a ways to include these symbols however that is what fixed my issue.